# Import data from EE2 to EE3 site

Tags: ee2, ee3, import, export

I am about to start work on a client site re-build.

The current site is running EE2. I plan on duplicating the site and then upgrading this duplication to EE3. The EE2 would continue to run as usual, with the re-build built on the duplication.

I am expecting the re-build to take around 3-4 months, in which time the live site will have a selection of new channel entries and members.

I need to find a way to bring over these new channel entries and members to the EE3 re-build site.

During the re-build, I will be modifying some of the existing channels. Some fields are going to be removed, possibly renamed or deleted. I will also be adding new fields.

Does anyone have any ideas if/how this can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no silver bullet unfortunately. I'd bring in the latest site to local. Upgrade local to V3. On local create/rename fields but don't delete.

Document every change to the channels & fields because once your local setup is ready you will have to set live to offline.

Then update to EE3 then update all channels & fields to match local. Then upload all new assets (templates, CSS etc).

It is a much talked about issue but there is no real solution, to my knowledge, other then what I've outlined.

Answer (score 1):

Late answer i know... But i tend to always use Datagrab:
http://brandnewbox.co.uk/products/details/datagrab